# How can I remove latex paint from wall?

Tags: removal

I partly re-painted the wall using latex paint (Rust Oleum-Ultra Cover Multi-Purpose Gloss Brush-On Paint) due to some scratches on the wall, but I failed to match the color. I was wondering if it was possible to get rid of the new paint.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, how much effort would you like to put in to it?

The easiest way is to paint over it.

Then there is manually or machine sanding all of the paint off.

Another option is using a paint stripper and chemically removing the paint.

Both of these last methods are quite labor intensive and make a mess.

I would buy some paint samples. Paint some scrap drywall or pieces of white cardboard. Choose a complementary color or contrasting color. Then paint one entire wall break-to-break. Or just repaint the entire room.

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

1st it sounds like the (Rust Oleum-Ultra Cover Multi-Purpose Gloss Brush-On Paint) is not latex paint.  I have been in the drywall and painting business for many years and agree with the answers above with one exception. 
I would either skim coat with drywall mud to get a smooth surface then sand and prime spray painted area then continue to paint entire wall with a color that is close to old color.  Remember that a flat paint also will hide imperfections more than satin or gloss.
Hope this helps...PC

Comment: The [datasheet](http://www.rustoleum.com/~/media/DigitalEncyclopedia/Documents/RustoleumUSA/TDS/English/CBG/Painters%20Touch/PTUC-01_Painters_Touch_Multi-Purpose_Gloss_Brush-On_Paint_TDS.ashx) for this paint says "Resin Type Water-based Acrylic" = latex in American English.